# Flexbox not working in Chrome, works in firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, flexbox

So below is a picture of what my flexbox (highlighted in red) looks like in Firefox. Here the behavior is as intended.

Code (vue html, also using bootstrap-vue components):

```
<div style="display: flex; background-color: red; justify-content: right;">
 <b-button class="mb-2" style="position: relative; right: 40px;"  size="sm" variant="danger" v-if="forceSyncMode" @click="applyForceSync()">Apply All</b-button>
 <b-button class="mb-2" style="position: relative; right: 23px;" size="sm" v-if="forceSyncMode" variant="secondary" @click="selectAllForceSync()">Select All</b-button>
 <b-button class="mb-2" style="position: relative; right: 5px;" size="sm" v-if="forceSyncMode" variant="secondary" @click="deselectAllForceSync()">Deselect All</b-button>
</div>
```

[image]
Now in google chrome it appears as such

[image]

This is probably just a rookie mistake, but I really can't figure out why the flex box would work on Firefox but not Chrome. What is going on here?

**Note:**  I haven't checked IE or Opera yet.

**Edit 1:** I Checked in IE and it has the same result as chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<div style="display: flex; background-color: red; justify-content:flex-end;">
 <b-button class="mb-2" style="position: relative; right: 40px;"  size="sm" variant="danger" v-if="forceSyncMode" @click="applyForceSync()">Apply All</b-button>
 <b-button class="mb-2" style="position: relative; right: 23px;" size="sm" v-if="forceSyncMode" variant="secondary" @click="selectAllForceSync()">Select All</b-button>
 <b-button class="mb-2" style="position: relative; right: 5px;" size="sm" v-if="forceSyncMode" variant="secondary" @click="deselectAllForceSync()">Deselect All</b-button>
</div>
```

may be u should use it like this

[justify-content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content)

Answer (score 0):

Try to,

`justify-content: flex-end;`

this should work in both browsers.

Here is an article of the flexbox guide from CSS-Tricks:
[Here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/j/justify-content/)